# I want to do an input validation on an int(), but validate for str()

Tags: python, validation, debugging, python-3.x, optimization

I want the code to "break" when the user's input is <=0 AND when the input = "stop".
This is what I have so far.

```
while True:

    try:
        x = input("how many times do you want to flip the coin?: ")
        if int(x) <= 0 or x.lower() == "stop": 
            break
        x = int(x)
        coinFlip(x)


     except ValueError:
        print ()
        print ("Please read the instructions carefully and try one more time! :)")
        print ()
```

I get the error:

```
    if int(x) <= 0 or str(x).lower() == "stop":
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'stop'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you get the exception because the first condition that's evaluated is `int(x) <= 0` and x is not really an integer at this point.

you can change the order of the the conditions:

```
if x.lower() == 'stop' or int(x) <=0
```

this way you check for `'stop'` first, and don't evaluated `int(x)` (because the the `or` condition already evaluates to `True`). any string that is not an integer and not `'stop'` would cause the `ValueError` exception which you're already handling.

Answer (score 1):

You get a `ValueError` because you can't convert the string `'stop'` to an integer.

One way to solve this would be to use a helper method that correctly catches the `ValueError` and then checks if the string is `stop`:

```
def should_stop(value):
    try:
        return int(value) <= 0
    except ValueError:
        return value.lower() == "stop"

while True:
    x = input("how many times do you want to flip the coin?: ")
    if should_stop(x): 
        break
```